# Why is pyinstaller not loading/executing

Tags: python, ios, pyinstaller

Whenever I try and use pyinstaller after installing it using pip install (on mac), I receive the following errors. Can someone help me resolve this. Use which pyinstaller finds the path, but trying to add to $PATH does not find it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3095, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3081, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 660, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 673, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 851, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (altgraph 0.10.2 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python), Requirement.parse('altgraph>=0.15'), set(['macholib']))
```

This is the output of adding to $PATH:

```
$PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller
-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error... was able to solve it by installing an updated altgraph package under my user's python path.  Hope this helps someone else that finds this page.

```
pip install --user altgraph==0.15
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  Worked for me as well.  Working in Python 2.7 is becoming increasingly difficult.  <grin>